Performance Issue when persistence is activated in Ignite
I am currently building some tests to compare performance between various options we could use as IMDG and found a performance “issue” with apache Ignite 2.16.0  when activating persistence, I am not quite sure what’s wrong.
Do you see any issues with my use case implementation and settings that could help ? Is it known to be slower than others, or is there some settings I could try ?
My keys are a java class with a few strings for a total of ~1KB
My Values are a java class as well with several string values ranging from 1KB to several MB (it’s a blob in string form)
I wrote a java test client with this configuration for Ignite:
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration()
        .setAddresses(addresses)
        .setPartitionAwarenessEnabled(true);



BinaryConfiguration binaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration();
BinaryTypeConfiguration binaryTypeConfiguration = new BinaryTypeConfiguration( "data.*" );
binaryTypeConfiguration.setSerializer(new IgniteModelBinarySerializer());
cfg.setBinaryConfiguration(binaryConfiguration);
try (IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg)) {
// my test code

}


The putAll code is below:

Map<TestKeyIgnite, TestValueIgnite> values = new HashMap<>();
// fill values here

long begin = System.nanoTime();

cache.putAll(values);

long end = System.nanoTime();


Ignite configuration is as close to default as possible, I’m starting it using ./apache-ignite-2.16.0-bin/bin/ignite.sh passing my configuration file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="workDirectory" value="<mymachine>/work"/>

        <property name="sqlConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.SqlConfiguration">
                <property name="queryEnginesConfiguration">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.calcite.CalciteQueryEngineConfiguration">
                            <property name="default" value="true"/>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="metricsLogFrequency" value="30000"/>
        <property name="gridLogger">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j2.Log4J2Logger">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="../config/ignite-log4j.xml"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="region0"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                                                                               <property name="backups" value="1"/>                   
                </bean>
                <!--same for other caches...-->
                                               </list>
                               </property>
    </bean>
</beans>



I tried changing WAL mode (I kept LOG_ONLY), and WAL size (64MB to 512MB) without any major improvements.
I also tried Direct IO mode (-J-DIGNITE_DIRECT_IO_ENABLED=true), IGNITE_USE_ASYNC_FILE_IO_FACTORY=false and writeThrottling without much difference either.
Results of the tests
I’m a bit lost on what to look for now, and what I can do to try to improve the persistence throughput for Ignite, or if it’s just ‘normal’.

Slower compared to what? Enabling persistence basically turns Ignite into a database, so writes will be slower than memory-only clusters. Bulk loads are sometimes performed with the WAL turned off. You also don't mention your Java configuration. It would be relevant if you saw "long JVM pauses" in your logs. Also, Ignite is a distributed system. Running as a single node isn't common.

Slower comparing to Ignite and Infinispan

If you want to compare to Infinispan, surely you need to turn off Ignite's persistence? Otherwise you're comparing a purely in-memory cache to a database.
